# Sequelize self association creates extra column

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following model defined with Sequelize:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Genre = sequelize.define('Genre', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        Genre.hasMany(models.Genre, {as: 'subGenre'});
        Genre.belongsTo(models.Genre, {as: 'parentGenre'});
      }
    }
  });

  return Genre;
}
```

The idea is that there will be parent genres, and each *may* have several sub-genres.  When I run `sync()`, the table is created fine, but there is an extra column (`GenreId`) that I can't quite explain:

```
"id";"integer";
"name";"character varying";255
"createdAt";"timestamp with time zone";
"updatedAt";"timestamp with time zone";
"GenreId";"integer";
"parentGenreId";"integer";
```

The sensible way to interpret the model is to only have a `parentGenreId` column, but I am not sure how to define that bi-directional relationship (genre may have parent, genre may have many children) with only one column being added.

How can I rework the model to allow the relationship to be defined correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use `through` (not tested)

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Genre = sequelize.define('Genre', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          Genre.hasMany(models.Genre, {as: 'children', foreignKey: 'ParentId'});
          Genre.belongsTo(models.Genre, {as: 'parent', foreignKey: 'ParentId'});
        }
      }
});

  return Genre;
}
```

So you could have `Genre#getChilren` and `Genre#getParent`

EDIT: Due to @mick-hansen, `through` applies for `belongsToMany`, not useful for this case. My fault. Corrected using his recommendation

Comment: No such thing as `through` for belongsTo, however it will likely create a join table on the hasMany. For this he likely just wants `foreignKey: 'ParentId'` to make sure both sides of the relationship use the same foreignKey